# brownie local testing with ganache fails

Tags: chainlink

Following the steps taken in the bootcamp day2 video on testing solidity contracts with brownie, I stumbled upon an error when testing the chainlink-mix scripts locally.

Here are the steps are taken to introduce the error:

1. execute brownie compile
2. execute genache-cli in separate terminal
3. execute brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py
4. brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/02_read_price_feed.py

ganache is selected as the default network and the server is listening on the ip/port 127.0.0.1:8545.

```
brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/02_read_price_feed.py
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

ChainlinkMixProject is the active project.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/brownie/network/main.py:44: BrownieEnvironmentWarning: Development network has a block height of 14
  warnings.warn(
Attached to local RPC client listening at '127.0.0.1:8545'...

Running 'scripts/price_feed_scripts/02_read_price_feed.py::main'...
<brownie.network.contract.ContractContainer object at 0x10e410dc0>
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/price_feed_scripts/02_read_price_feed.py", line 7, in main
    price_feed_contract = PriceFeedConsumer[-1]
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 175, in __getitem__
    return self._contracts[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

ganache is set as default network in the brownie-config.yaml

Comment: Welcome, and can you please provide your ``brownie-config.yaml`` and environment parameters? Try launching the run without starting ganache-cli. Mine gets started by brownie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brownie doesn't save the location of deployed contracts to a local running chain by default since they get deleted so often and would take up a ton of space, so you have to tell brownie to remember stuff deployed to ganache.

In your `brownie-config.yaml` add

```
dev_deployment_artifacts: true
```

And rerun your scripts